# GetResponse from a webrequest object fails to with authentication issue

Tags: c#

```
Stream FeedReader(string url_)
{
    var url = url_;

    var USER = "username";
    var PASS = "password";


    //var encoded = TextToBase64(USER + ":" + PASS);

    WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
   // myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    //myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
    myWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(USER, PASS); 
    myWebRequest.Timeout = 10000;
    //WebResponse response = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
    var stream = myWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream() ;
    return stream;
}
```

I have no idea why I always have got error (connection timeout) after calling this function, I hope someone could be of help. Please don't hesitate to help me, thank you so very very much......

```
    public static List<Item> ParseAtom2(Stream stream)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);//("atom.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

        var entries = doc.Root
             .Descendants(ns + "entry")
             .Select(item => new Item
             {
                 FeedType = FeedType.Atom,
                 Content = item.Element(ns + "content").Value,
                 Link = "",//(string)item.Element(ns + "link").Attribute("href").Value,
                 PublishDate = DateTime.Parse(item.Element(ns + "published").Value),
                 Title = item.Element(ns + "title").Value
             });
        stream.Close();
        return entries.ToList();
    }
```

That is the second function I use the stream returned from the first one as an argument. And I always get a timeout connection error.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're not closing the stream, which hopefully closes the response too. (You'd normally dispose of the response explicitly.) I would at least *consider* creating a copy of the stream in this method. It's easy in .NET 4:

```
using (var response = myWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
    MemoryStream copy = new MemoryStream();
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(copy);
    }
    copy.Position = 0;
    return copy;
}
```

If you don't dispose of resources properly, the connection pool will think you're still using the connection, and there's a limit to the number of connections per host.

(Assuming I'm right and you're not closing the stream elsewhere, you should do that too - in general, make sure you always close your resources.)

Comment: Thank you but I wish I understood what you mean. Ialways get the connection timeout error, and I am not connecting to the site

Comment: @Giovani: Which bit? You're fetching a stream - are you doing that with a `using` statement, or disposing/closing the stream in any other way?

Comment: I will use that stream as an argument in another function, and I close it after I get the data from it

Comment: @Giovani: Okay, this may not be the problem then. However, I would generally suggest that you close the stream in whatever calls your first method, rather than in `ParseAtom2`. Keep the ownership model as simple as possible. Also, use `using` directives to avoid resource leaks if there are exceptions. I suggest you try the post in my code - aside from anything else, that will make sure you've really closed the *response*, not just the stream.